# Slow wifi speeds and ethernet ports in house not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, nas

I am brand new to networking and find it really interesting, but also very confusing. First of all, I have a Google Nest Wifi (one wan & lan port) with two wireless access points (doesn't support ethernet; plugs into wall. Here are some pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I don't think I have a modem, I just have a white cable that plugs into the WAN port of my router. All those hanging cables (cat 5e?), I think, are connected to the ethernet ports in walls throughout my house. Those ports aren't currently working and I think this is why. I only need a few working though; my priority is the one in my room.

Internet speed right next to my router (in basement): 340mbps; 14ms ping Speed across basement next to stairs: 136mbps; 97ms ping Speed next to the point upstairs from basement (D's Office): 77mbps; 16ms ping Speed next to the point upstairs (top floor) from previous point (P's Office): 44mbps; 19ms ping Speed in my bedroom (top floor; other side of floor from top floor point: 10mbps; 10ms ping

Google Home's wifi speed test: 847mbps download; 748mbps upload

Mesh test: D's Office's point: Good connection P's Office's point: Weak connection

I am want to start hardwiring devices as well. I think I may be able to purchase a managed 8-port 1gb ethernet switch from Amazon to plug in the cables (ones in basement that were just hanging there) and connect that switch to the lan port on my router in the basement. In my bedroom (currently has 10mbps wireless), I have a single ethernet port, but a bunch of devices that I want to hardwire. I am planning on buying a 5-port ethernet switch (unmanaged) a plugging a cable from the wall to the switch. Then I can plug all my devices (desktop, NAS, etc.) into that.

If possible, it would be nice to move my router upstairs to the ground floor of the house (center floor) and have a point in the basement and one on the top floor. Although, I tried this and it didn't seem to work. I plugged the router into a random Ethernet port and it didn't receive any internet connection (even with the router in the basement, the ports still don't work). Although I haven't tried a powerline adapter (I think they're bad?) or extending the white cable plugged into the wan port a floor up as that would cause issues with activating the Ethernet ports in my house.

For the NAS, I am planning on buying a Synology one. Synology 4 bay NAS DiskStation DS418 (Diskless) or Synology 4-Bay DiskStation DS923+ (Diskless), though I don't know which one would suit me best. I want to use it to store terabytes of files from all the devices in my house as well as hosting VM's and Docker containers (AdGuard & Home Assistant). I am aware I need fast internet speeds for this and plan to hard wire this. It will be kept in my bedroom upstairs, plugged into the 5-port Ethernet switch.

**My problem is that I am paying for 1 Gigabit internet speeds, but not taking advantage of it. Based on everything I wrote, how can I change my current setup to optimize my internet speeds (wireless and hardwired) and activate the Ethernet ports around my house in order to hardwire a NAS?**

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.